# Removing html tags with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

First off, I understand that it is not ideal to parse html with regex.  However, I'm close to the solution I need, and I just can't quite get it right.

Say you have html input in a string and you do:

```
content = content.replaceAll("<[^\\P{Graph}>]+>", "");
```

This will essentially remove html tags except those with non-printable characters, space, tab, newline, and control characters.

This is fine, except that there is a problem with the space character.  I need to `replaceAll` tags that look like:

```
<ht ml> (space somewhere in the middle)
```

but keep those that look like:

```
< html> (because this one contains a space as the FIRST character).
```

How can I adjust my regular expression for `replaceAll()` to accomplish this?  Thanks for any input/suggestions.

Comment: What about when the space is at the very last? `<html >`?

Comment: @Unihedron That tag should be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Place an optional group after your negated class.

```
content = content.replaceAll("<[^\\P{Graph}>]+(?: [^\\P{Graph}>]*)*>", "");
```

Since you're first checking for these characters after the opening bracket, this may suffice as well.

```
content = content.replaceAll("<[^\\P{Graph}>]+(?: [^>]*)?>", "");
```